# How to find the minimum-maximum of $ N( 0, 1) $

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, order-statistics

Given that two random variables $J,P∼N(0,1)$ are independent. Show how to compute the following and provide the answer:

(i) $E[\min(J,P)]$ and $E[\min(J^2,P^2)]$ and

(ii) $E[\max(J,P)]$ and $[\max(P^2,J^2)].$

A similar question was posted about 6 years ago, click [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255211/what-is-covx-y-where-x-minu-v-and-y-maxu-v-for-independent-normal0-1-va?noredirect=1&lq=1) to see it. I followed the steps over there to try to solve this question. I understand there may be several ways of solving this question and I welcome any alternative methods in solving the question. However, here’s my understanding so far which may not be entirely correct:

I will let $D = \min(J,P)$ and $N=\max(J,P).$
It is a fact that $D+N = J+P.$ Then we can able to present the following:

$$ E(D)+E(N) = E(J) + E(P) = 0; \quad E(D)= -E(N)$$
Note that
$$ 2E(D) = E(D)-E(N) = E(D-N)=E(|J - P|), \ \text{(expectation of half-normal random variable)}$$

$$2E(D) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}; \quad E(D) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \quad E(N) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}.$$

$W = \sum_{i=1}^k Z_i^2$ is a $\chi^2$ distribution, where $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$.  Let $A = \min(J^2,P^2)$ and $B= \max(J^2,P^2) .$

$$ E(A) + E(B) =E(J^2) + E(P^2) =2$$
$$E(A) = 2-E(B)$$

$$E(A)=E(B)=1.$$

Comment: I didn't trust that part especially I had $E(A) = E(B) = 1$ is this correct?

Comment: Oops. This does not look perfectly correct, sorry. I read too fast and thought it was the square of the min, or max. 
In your case, the sum of the two expectations is correct, but you have $\mathbb{E}(A) < \mathbb{E}(B)$, indeed

Comment: Your help is most welcome. I interested in knowing the correct solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last part, you already know that $\mathbb{E}(A+B)=2$, and all you have to do is find the value of $\mathbb{E}(B-A)$, which is not zero this time.

Indeed, $\mathbb{E}(B-A) = \mathbb{E}(|J^2 - P^2|)$. Given $\theta$ uniformly distributed on $[0, 2\pi[$ independent from $R$ with density $f(r) = r e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}$, $r \ge 0$, use polar coordinates to write $(J,P) \sim (R\cos\theta, R\sin\theta)$, and then: $$\mathbb{E}(B-A) = \mathbb{E}(R^2)\mathbb{E}\big(|\cos(\theta)^2-\sin(\theta)^2|\big) = 2 \cdot \mathbb{E}(|\cos(2\theta)| = \frac{4}{\pi}$$

Hence $\mathbb{E}(A) = 1 - \frac{2}{\pi}$ and $\mathbb{E}(B) = 1 + \frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: Remark: a simple way to get $\mathbb{E}(R^2)=2$ is to note that $R^2 = R^2(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) = J^2 + P^2$

Comment: I never knew we could use polar coordinates for this question. Is there a general way to figure out when is it appropriate to apply polar coordinates to any question?

Comment: @holala I cannot think of a general way. At first I tried to think about what I knew about the distribution of $|J^2-P^2|$, and even $J^2-P^2$. The answer was: not much.
Since I didn't want to tackle the double integral by hand, I thought about a representation in polar coordinates, noticed that I could factor a neat $|\cos(2\theta)|$ and I went with it. This approach would not have worked at all if you were trying to compute $\mathbb{E}(|J^2 - P|)$ for instance